# How can you add a user phone number in the same child as email?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Use Case: App build around email (with three childs of importance here). Now I just want cell phone login users to have the same Childs.
So something like this below must not produce an error(it currently does). I can do everything else with phone login (even create a user with phone number), but I want him to have these Childs too, for when the user uses phone and not email.

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: ResultString, password: remainingPart) { (user, error) in
  let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
  guard error == nil else { return }
  guard let user = user else { return }
  let userObject =
    [
      "users": ResultString,
      "postID": user.user.uid,
      "e2": remainingPart,
    ] as [String: Any]

  databaseRef.child("people").child(user.user.uid).setValue(userObject)
  print("YESSSSS")
}
```

Comment: Which part of the code you shared isn't doing what you expect it to do?

Comment: YESSSSS never gets printed. The `Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: ResultString, password: remainingPart) { (user, error)` sees it as an error because `ResultString` is a phone number not an emails and `remainingPart` is the last 4 digits of the phone number, not an actual password. I guess though the issue is the email being a phone number and not having an @

Comment: If there is an error in `createUser(withEmail:, password:)` then the `error` variable tells you what went wrong. I recommend inspecting that value.

Comment: I tried it, it prints out: `Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17008 "The email address is badly formatted." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The email address is badly formatted., FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL} error .` So that is as I thought the phone number don't get accepted as email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're trying to pass a phone number to `createUser(withEmail:,password:)`. Since a phone number is not a valid email address, the API rejects it.

To sign a user in with their phone number, follow the documentation for [phone number sign-in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth).

After singing the user in with their phone number, you can still write their details to the database, same as you're doing now.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. But how would you handle uid in that case, ie assuming user has been created with phone number and segues to the next page

Comment: I have no idea what you mean there. Can you clarify?

Comment: What I mean is how would that look, writing to the database? So in `databaseRef.child("people").child(user.user.uid).setValue(userObject)`, what would you make the `user.user.uid` part?

Comment: If the user is signed in that'd be `Auth.auth().currentUser.uid`. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users